# mysql_query("START TRANSACTION")- Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction in Codeigniter Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-3

I used `mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");` in my code. does it causes this error?

Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction in codeigniter mysql on update query.

I tried to change innodb_lock_wait_timeout to 100 on phpmyadmin, which is 50 now
but it gives np previlage error and the value remains 50.
Is there a way to solve the issue in my code.
i dont know what i do wrong on code

Is there a way to use `mysql_query("START TRANSACTION")` in codeigniter

Comment: mysql_query was deprecated in PHP v5.5.0 and removed from PHP at v7.0.0  - it should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

Transactions are managed in CI as **below:**

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

You can refer [this](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html) official link of documentation.

Comment: i think using core php mysql_query("START TRANSACTION"); is same as using active record class

Comment: @roopesh, When the framework is giving you a way then why to use native PHP function. I didn't understand.

To your question: *Is there a way to use mysql_query("START TRANSACTION") in codeigniter*, the answer has been given.